# How to get the position of the last match of a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that matches numbers and I want to get the position of the last-matching number.

This is what I got right now:

```
def find_last_match_pos(pattern, s):
    match = None
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
        pass
    return match.start() if match else -1
```

Can anyone think of a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Yeah I'm confident about the loop, I'm just wondering if there could be a clever trick involving `re`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it appears it's not a duplicate because their is a solution specific to regular expressions.

Comment: I wouldn't say that that solution was more efficient, myself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use findall?

```
s.rfind(re.findall(pattern, s)[-1])
```

Comment: Neat! Totally forgot about `str.rfind`.